# Adding PWA to angular 8 - module build failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have angular 8 app.
Inside this app I have three projects.

I want to add `@angular/pwa` with this command

```
ng add @angular/pwa && ng build --prod
```

But when PWA is installed I get error

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/fesm2015/service-worker.js
>       Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
>       'C:\Development\Repositories\app\node_modules@angular\service-worker\fesm2015\service-worker.js'

and in CHROME CONSOLE i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34469)
    at core.js:34487
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34483)
    at core.js:34487
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34483)
    at core.js:34487
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:34483)
```

Before PWA everything working ok

EDIT: I also try to remove PWA and add it directly to project

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project app1
```

And now in my project `src`, I get new file `manifest.webmanifest`, in the root of project I get `ngsw-config.json`, and in project module I get `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`

But still, get the same error

EDIT:

Here is my folder structure.  This is all how angular CLI is added. Do I need to add another file?

I don't have `gsw-worker.js` in any of my folders.

Also, when I  open `ngsw-config.json` for `"$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json"` i get

`Unable to load schema from c:\Development\Repositories\app\app-frontend\node_modules\@angular\service-worker\config\schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Development\Repositories\app\app-frontend\node_modules\@angular\service-worker\config\schema.json'`

But if i look in `node_modules` shema.json is there

```
(root -angular.json, package.json... there is no any manifest.webmanifest and ngsw-config.json)
 |
 |
 |----projects
        |
        |----app1
               |------src
               |       |------app
               |       |        |-app.module.ts (here is in imports ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })) 
               |       |
               |       |-manifest.webmanifest
               |
               |
      ngsw-config.json
      tsconfig.json
      tsconfig.app.json
      tsconfig.spec.json
```

Mabey in ma app.module.ts (in my project) is the problem because I need to register `'ngsw-worker.js'` but I can not find anywhere this in my app, mabey angular CLI not added this or I don't need this file?

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to make it working...

- `npm uninstall @angular/pwa`
- `npm cache clean`

> Random errors§
>   Some strange issues can be resolved by simply running npm cache clean and trying again.
>   If you are having trouble with npm install, use the -verbose option to see more details.

- after all of this `ng update`

This will fix this error.
This error happens because some of dependency in package.json is not up-to-date and they make mess with pwa.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that adding PWA is adding this features to one of the existing projects with the command below:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

Check the official documentation from angular for more information: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple errors in your application try to add pwa again properly with

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

and then build it with

```
ng build --prod
```

here is the link for your reference - https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

**Chrome console error**

you are getting that error cause u are tying to access id from an object which is not defined for that you need to handle your object properly

for ex- `let id = obj.id ? obj.id : '';`

Try to fix that error first and then build it. If it doesn't work then remove your node_modules and then install it again and build it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thx. I always check as you described, but this problem is something with PWA directly... I removed completely PWA from my app and install as you suggest, but the same problem is here...  if I build without PWA there is no errors.

Comment: what do you mean by having three project in same directory ? Are these three different angular project ?And check one more thing that  are u adding pwa in the main application directory ?

Comment: I edit my question... i have one angular app with multiple project inside

Comment: @Arter I wrote an article to add step by step PWA to an Angular app: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular the post also refers to a working Github Angular 8 PWA project you can refer to for comparison.

Comment: @Francesco thnx... I already uae your tutorial for this. But problem was with npm dependecy versions

Answer (score 1):

Few thing before you install pwa to angular project. First you need to update your @angular/cli to make sure you have lastest version

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Then run

```
ng new projectname
```

Then add pwa to your project

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

And run

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: I edit my question, pls take a look. Also, I get last CLI version

Comment: Hard to solve. Can you update your code to github I would love to help you

Comment: thnx for your help, but I can not update my code to any public platform before release... iI try to make another question, simplified