# When i am trying to install @angular/pwa. Using ng add @angular/pwa. It shows me this error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Kevin Shah\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'
Fatal error writing debug log file: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Kevin Shah\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Kevin Shah\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'

```
  at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1646:7)
  at Object.installTempPackage (C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\install-package.js:45:56)
  at AddCommand.run (C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\add-impl.js:141:48)
  at async AddCommand.validateAndRun (C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:134:28)
  at async Object.runCommand (C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:201:24)
  at async default_1 (C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:62:31)
```

Even though i am installing it in 'C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\Angular\ng-pwa01-start' folder, it shows 'C:\Users\Kevin Shah\AppData\Local\Temp;C' this folder error.

I have even tried running 'ng add @angular/pwa --project ng-pwa01-start', but it also shows me same error.

Comment: Angular CLi may dont have right permission to that folder path . check windows permission on that folder first

Comment: did you installed `@angular/service-worker` ?

Comment: Have you tried right click on your `cmd`, than `run as administrator ` and type in your command in your project folder?

Comment: Have you initialized your angular project first of all? Also try `npm uninstall @angular/pwa` and than `npm cache clean`

Comment: Yes, I tried using 'ng add @angular/service-worker' it shows me **The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.**, this error

Comment: Yes, I have even tried running it as an administrator. It shows the same error

Comment: How can i check CLi permission ?

Comment: I even uninstall @angualr/pwa it shows 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936624/2976876

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: Resolved. Thank you guys for your help..!!